# Howto watch Ubuntu One files (Cloud)?

Tags: ubuntu-one, application-development, python

Is there a library to add Ubuntu One files (cloud) monitoring facility into my app, e.g. to watch certain folder for the changes?

Comment: have you logged into at the Ununtu One website  @ http://one.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @StephenMyall I want to include monitoring facility into the program I'm writing or could you clarify your questions, pls?

Comment: Are you interested in the state of the cloud version of the files, or the local copy?  If you are only interested in the local copy, then any of the existing file change notification APIs should do.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge the state of the cloud version of the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is no *realtime* notification of file changes to cloud files. However, if you're happy to poll, you can retrieve the data for a directory with the cloud files API at https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud. You can also retrieve the `generation` for a volume (a whole synced folder); any change to anything in that synced folder will increment the generation number, so it's the first thing to look at if you're polling.